# How to input integer numbers with space in between

Tags: c++, input, integer

I have to input integer numbers and do operation on each of them. Each integer will be separated by a space between them,  and the number of integers are not defined,

So input may be 1 23 45 80 or 21 32.

I tired using cin,  it didn't work,  as on space it breaks.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? And then we can explicitly talk about why it's not working.

Comment: I couldn't do because of this. I encountered thus problem in a test I had. I wasn't able to take input. It was online and the inputs were like. 21 32 58 65 80 or 21 32...  It can vary the number of numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int x;
while(cin>>x)
{
  store the number one by one
}
//process
```

Simply do it this way. Store the numbers in the array.
Or you can do it this way-

```
string s;
getline(cin,s);
std::stringstream myss;
myss<<s;
std::string t;
int x;
std::vector<int> v;
while(std::getline(myss,t,' '))
{
    if(std::stringstream(t)>>x)
    {
       // store x in an vector. 
       v.push_back(x);
    }
```

Let's elaborate the idea-

> What is **stream**? Informally, a string is a collection of characters, a stream is a tool to manipulate moving data around.
>
> What is **stringstream**? A class that operate on strings.Objects of this class use a string buffer that contains a sequence of characters. This sequence of characters can be accessed directly as a `string` object, using member `str`.
>
> How the first code works? `cin` is an object of class `istream` that represents the standard input stream.(from where inputs are fetched) It returns a reference to the same stream for which it is overloaded here `istream`. `cin` is used for formatted string extraction.It's possible to make tests like
>      if (cin)
>        //then do something.
>   which will be `true` if `cin` is ok and `false` if an end-of-file or has encountered an error. It can be used easily in case you are reading from a file.
>
> How the second code works? Simply put it this way. Upto the ' ' you are putting a whole line in a `string`. Then you are using the `stringstream` class to get the desired value (here int x). Now when you are extracting from it, you are only extracting a int value. After that it again goes to getline to fetch the next number. As space seperates the numbers each getline is getting a string containing that number. The getline works as follows- **getline(cin,str,delim)**
>   extracts characters from cin and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n' where the delim is not there [means `getline(cin,str)`]),
>
> The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in is or if some other error occurs during the input operation.
>   If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it.
>   Each extracted character is appended to the string.
>
> Now this is how the second code works. Check reference manuals for more deatils.

Now let's see a little bit about `vector`s.

> vector is a container type in c++. The next question would be probably what is **conatiner**?
>
> **container**: containers are holder objects that store collection of other objects. Simply put, you can keep anything in this containers, be it a int or a object you defined or structure type, anything. This is flexibilty is acieved using template. The template as the name implies simply give us a idea about it's work-yes it is a template of any type you can use in place of it.
>
> **vector**: There are other containers like list,deque etc but vector is quite different from other containers. Vector is quite effiecient where it has to insert or delete element from ends( back end) and access elements randomly- vector provides random access easily like `v[i]` etc. This is the basic of vector. It is better than arrays because it increases dynamically as you push elements. To know how to use it check the reference manual.

Comment: I cannot using in array. As I don't know how long the cin must repeat and the number of numbers I don't know.

Comment: Also,  can we do while(cin>>x)??  When will it stop executing. When will it store value and where?

Comment: @SebuElias.: Look at my current answer. I have included a modified answer.

Comment: Could u please explain. I can't understand the code. Vector and string stream I am not familiar with.

Comment: @SebuElias.: I will elaborate in my answer. Have you checked the code? Hope you have no problem with it.

Comment: Ss or s inside the while loop?? And also,  how is the first code work??  Simple while(cin>> x)??

Comment: I don't mean to be irritating. But I cannot understand the second code as the terms vector(I will look up now)  and string stream are new to me.

Comment: @SebuElias.: Just wait. I am modifying my answer to suit your need.

Comment: @SebuElias.: Now check it. It will be much more clear.

Comment: huge thanks.  I understood what u told.  Really huge thanks for spending time for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: could you give a quick word on vector.  Please

Comment: @SebuElias.: Okay! I will add a brief description of vectors in my answer shortly.

Comment: @SebuElias.: Check the new added content. Hope it will help.